# Why doesn't the down key go to the end of the line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, browser, word-processing

I like being able to use the down arrow key to move the cursor to the end of the line if its already at the last line and can't go any lower. Likewise, I like being able to use the up arrow key to move the cursor to the beginning of the line if its already at the first line and can't go any higher.

I'm using Windows 10, and every word processor does nothing when I press up at the top line or down at the bottom line. I want up and down to behave like home and end in those cases. I've tested this in Word 2016, Wordpad, and Notepad, as well as input fields in some non-Microsoft programs like HeidiSQL and DB Browser for SQLite.

Word Online also has the bad behavior. However, most online text input fields depend on which browser I'm using. The Microsoft browsers Internet Explorer and Edge have the bad behavior. But Chrome and Firefox do what I want in most input fields, including the one I'm typing in now.

Is there any way to get the up and down keys to behave more intuitively in all cases instead of acting like they've hit a wall? Or at least in Word?

Comment: I don't know of any such general option across all installed products,
or even for Word alone. You will need to write a VBA macro to intercept the down-key, check you are in the last line, and convert it to an end-key. It's really too much work.

Comment: It seems to depend on the individual applications: WinWord and WordPad stick at the current column; NotePad changes the current column whenever a line is encountered which is too short to position on the current column; NotePad++ works as you would like, even remembering the initial column on moving back. I'm not sure that this behaviour is necessarily intuitive.

Comment: Why the down vote and close vote? While my preference is a matter of opinion, that could be applied to any question. The question isn't opinion-based and the answers wouldn't be opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that it is *not possible* to perform that action within Windows 10 using the standard software you have mentioned. That doesn't mean you cannot work around it though.

To go to the end or beginning of a line your 'Go To' keys would be 'Home' and 'End'.

If you prefer to remap Home/End to function with your Arrow keys then this is possible by writing a simple script using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/).

You could make an extremely simple script where if you press Ctrl + Up Arrow it will do 'Home'. Or if you press Ctrl + Down Arrow it will do 'End'.

**Example Script 1:**

^Up::

Send, {Home}

**Example Script 2:**

^Down::

Send, {End}